# How to list more "Active Questions"?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, user-interface

When I visit stackoverflow.com, "Active" questions are displayed.  I get a list of 30 "active" questions followed by

> Looking for more? Browse the [complete list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest), or [popular tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).
>   Help us answer [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered).

The complete list, popular tags and unanswered questions are all paginated, (i.e. links to page "1", "2", ... "n" with 30 questions/page).  However, the "Active" questions pages only lists 30 questions, without the option of viewing more...  This brings up two questions:

1. How do I view additional "Active" questions?
2. Can I change the default to show more than 30 questions/page?

---

**Edit:**  Ahh, I new there was an obvious answer:

1. Click [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)
2. Select the [Active tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active)...

Why isn't this the default page when a user goes to http://www.stackoverflow.com/?

Comment: +1 for the edit - why aren't the pagination links available on the home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get more active questions by viewing the active tab in the Questions link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active

At the bottom there is a page selector so you can see as many questions as you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll all the way to the bottom of the Active page, on the right you'll see links that allow you to select from 15, 30, or 50 results per page.